# Putting image beside an input field using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I will like to put an image beside and input field using bootstrap. i want my output to be like :`[image]

but with the below code i get 
[image]

```
 <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputTitle" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Title</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>
        <input type="title" class="form-control" id="inputTitle" >
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you will provide a working sample it will be much easier to help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `form-control` class will make your input 100% wide, meaning it will flow onto the next line. Additionally, it will make it display as a `block` element.

If I were you, I would look at using [input groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) instead, this is a nice tidy way of achieving the same effect:

Also, you have given your text input a type of `title` which is not valid. It's likely just a `text` input.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

Comment: is it posible to also have two input side by side seperated with "-" for example to store zipcode and state

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">Title</label>
     <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"></span>
           <input type="text" class="form-control">
     </div>
</div>
```